# Getting Drag-Event without displaying anything

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-dragdrop

I have the following page using angular-dragdrop "ngDragDrop" (which uses the jQueryUI-Dragdrop)

the following code WORKS:

```
<div class="sourceContainer">
    <div ng-repeat="oldLocation in oldLocations"
        data-drag="true"
        data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone'}"
        ng-model="oldLocation"
        jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}}, animate: true, placeholder: 'keep'}"
        class="oldLocation singleTag"
        >{{oldLocation.name}}</div>
</div>
<div class="targetContainer" data-drop="true" ng-model='oldLocationsCopied' jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:false}">
    <div ng-repeat="newLocation in oldLocationsCopied track by $index"
        data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone'}"
        class="oldLocation singleTag"
        ng-model="newLocation" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true,onDrop:doDrop(newLocation.name)}">{{newLocation.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

So I can drag&drop DIVs from inside "sourceContainer" to "targetContainer" and the function "onDrop()" is called when I do that.

Now I want the same without ANY visible action. When a div is dragged, it should just disappear and the method onDrop() should be called.

I could just hide the targetContainer but there should be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery UI you can set `helper` to the DOM element you want to be dragged for feedback. See docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper

But it seems that setting it to anything but `original` will prevent from updating the position of the draggable element after drop. If you want that positioned updated, you should do it yourself like so:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    helper: function() {
        return $('<div>').appendTo($('body'));
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).css({position: 'relative', left: ui.position.left, top: ui.position.top}).show();
    },
    start: function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

I made this simple draggable demo with the code above without Angular: http://jsfiddle.net/tikosar/u2h332Lw/ . I think you can adjust it to your needs easily.